# gradle transitive dependencies across different repos

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

we are having some confusion here about about dependencies are resolved. we have thing like this,

```
repositories {
    maven { url "http://my.repo" }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

`my.repo` has a mish-mash of our locally built artifacts and copies of some standard artifacts.

my question is what happens if part of a dependency tree is found in `my.repo`. will it resolve part from `my.repo`, and part from `central`? for example, suppose we had this dependency tree,

```
depA
  depA1
depB
  depB1
```

now suppose these artifacts were located here,

```
my.repo: depA, depB1
central: depA2, depB
```

will gradle resolve depA1 from `central` even though the parent dependency is located in `my.repo`? will it resolve depB1 from `my.repo` even though it's parent dependency is located in `central`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle will not differentiate between repositories, though it will search the repositories in the order they are declared. I.e. all repositories for a configuration are used for resolving, the origin of the dependency won't affect which repositories transitive dependencies come from. In your example depA2 will be searched in "my.repo" first, then searched in "central".

Likewise, Gradle can not currently isolate a configuration to a set of repositories. Meaning that all configurations come from all repositories.